# Did St.Thomas really throw water in the air (in India) and it remained airborne?

Tags: christianity-in-india, thomas-apostle

I was told this during childhood, that this is how St.Thomas converted certain Hindu Brahmins to Christianity. Also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Thomas_Syro-Malabar_Catholic_Church,_Palayoor#Legend):

> Historical legend records that when St. Thomas landed at Palayur, he
>   witnessed the sight of Hindu Brahmins, after their ablutions in a
>   local tank, offering prayers by chanting mantras (the Vedic tradition
>   of India for spiritual transformation) hymns to god in the form of
>   Argyam or Tharpanam (water held in the palms) of water to the Sun god,
>   a practice also said to be followed in Harappan and Persian cultures.
>   Amused by the sight of water being thrown up by the Brahmins, from the
>   palms of their hands, which was falling back, he challenged the
>   Brahmins stating that the water they were offering was not being
>   accepted by the Sun god as it was falling back into the tank. He made
>   a deal with them stating that his God would accept the offer of water
>   if he threw it up in the same way as they did, but water would not
>   fall back. If he proved this then his God was superior and the
>   Brahmins would have to embrace Christianity. He performed this miracle
>   (summoned the Holy Trinity, completed the sign of the Cross and threw
>   water held in his palms up into the air, which remained still in the
>   air at a height) and with this miracle he converted a number of
>   Brahmins and Jews in Palayur to Christianity. Thereafter he baptised
>   the converts in a nearby water tank.

Is there any evidence or similar documented text outside India which confirms this miracle?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more detail, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). "Evidence" for miracles is difficult to verify, but perhaps there is documentation related to it that someone could point you to.

Comment: Thanks. By "evidence" I had actually meant any other confirmed reports of the miracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked for such an account in the recent *Synaxarion* compiled by the Monastery of Simonos Petra on Mt. Athos, as well as an English translation of Dmitri of Rostov's 17th century *Great Collection of The Lives of the Saints* and I can't find anything like this account.  Both of these works are multi-volume collections  and extremely detailed.  Dmitri of Rostov's account of St. Thomas' Life is 14 pages long, but doesn't have anything similar I could find.

The most famous account of St. Thomas in India seems to be how he collected money from a great King to build him a mansion, but kept giving the money to the poor.  When the King found out what he had done, he was furious and had Thomas imprisoned.  The King's brother died suddenly, though, and was vouchsafe a vision of heaven, where he saw an enormous golden mansion being built for his brother by virtue of Thomas' good deeds to the poor.  He came back to life and both he and his brother became Christians as a result.

Answer (score 1):

This so-called water miracle is an imaginary story to appropriate Brahmin status to a family belonging to a non-Brahmin, local caste. It's historically inaccurate because there were no Namboodiri Brahmins in Kerala in the 1st century C.E. Brahmins came in the 8th century and it's evidenced by the introduction of Sanskrit language after their arrival. Before the arrival of Namboodiris, proto-Tamil was the language of the land.
Another glaring twist in history is the fake claim there were Jews in Kerala. Solomon's ships came to India and other Eastern countries for trade and not to plant Jewish colonies. Solomon didn't establish Jewish colonies even in the Middle Eastern countries.
According to historical records, Jews came to Kerala only in 1000 C.E. under the leadership of Joseph Rabban during the regime of Bhaskara Ravivarman.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! If you could add some extra references to support what you're saying, such as there being no Namboodiri Brahmins in Kerala in the 1st century, that would improve this answer.

Comment: I agree. @Abraham, kindly validate your claims with references.